# Change background color of CMFCListCtrl header?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

For a `CMFCListCtrl` in a `CPropertyPage`, I want to change the background color of the header. There is a protected method of the header control `CMFCHeaderCtrl::OnFillBackground` (`virtual void OnFillBackground(CDC* pDC);`).

Can I use the `OnFillBackground` function to change the background color without creating any new classes or using custom draw?

MFC, C++, Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.5), Windows 11

Comment: Not really. Not only is the `OnFillBackground()` method protected, the object instance is created internally by the `CMFCListCtrl` class code, so you have almost no control over this. However, I think it is possible to do it writing really little code, but having to create a new `CMFCVisualManager`-derived class, with the `OnFillHeaderCtrlBackground()` method overridden.